# How to get state name and how to superimpose its value on heat map plot for USA in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot heat map for USA with state name and its value on it respectively. My code to get heat map is:

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
txt <- "AB  AK  AL  AN  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  EN  FL  GA  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS
    1  21  31   1  12  56 316  53  31  16   7   1 335  63  11  42  29  73  40  2"

dat <- stack(read.table(text = txt,  header = TRUE))
names(dat)[2] <-'state.abb'
dat$states <- tolower(state.name[match(dat$state.abb,  state.abb)])
mapUSA <- map('state', fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
nms <- sapply(strsplit(mapUSA$names,  ':'),  function(x)x[1])
USApolygons <- map2SpatialPolygons(mapUSA,  IDs = nms,  CRS('+proj=longlat'))
idx <- match(unique(nms),  dat$states)
dat2 <- data.frame(value = dat$value[idx], state = unique(nms))
row.names(dat2) <- unique(nms)

USAsp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(USApolygons,  data = dat2)
spplot(USAsp['value'])
```

This is previously defined code in stackoverflow that i used for my analysis but i need to add state label and its value on the plot.
The output i am getting here for this code:
[image: Heat map]
Here I need to display state name & its corresponding value on respective state. Please suggest solution for this.

Comment: Three quick questions: why are some of your states not standard abbreviations, such as AB and AN?  Second, how would levelplot add state names, for example, to a similar plot (it is referenced by spplot)?  What was the earlier SO question that provided the code you built on?

Comment: It is just an example code which i used for my heat map analysis so some state abbreviations have no meaning. You can check previous SO question "Create a heatmap of USA with state abbreviations and characteristic frequency in R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the     spplot      function to this:

```
spplot(USAsp['value'],panel = function(x,y,z,subscripts,...) {
  panel.polygonsplot(x,y,z,subscripts,...)
  sp.text(coordinates(USAsp[!is.na(USAsp$value),]), 
      paste(row.names(USAsp[!is.na(USAsp$value),]),"\n",USAsp$value[!is.na(USAsp$value)])) })
```

Adding the panel function to the plot allows you to add text at the coordinates where the states have a value in your data.